# Success checks for client-side javascript mini-game embedded within a server-side browser game

Tags: browser-based-games, security

**Disclaimer:** I know that client-side is always to be held with suspicion, but I'm trying to conceive of a way to verify the success or failure of javascript-based mini-games.

### Mini-games to add fun to client-side game

Here is an example scenario:

I implement a javascript-dependent picture-sliding game for various pictures.
You know the type:

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_AAvC0ZSs-1k/SUv8waQg0zI/AAAAAAAABN0/tzf3pA9nDxA/s400/SlidingPuzzle-ForHelen.jpg]

So that would be a javascript game that would be served from my website.

### How to check success

I then want to set up a verification scheme to verify that the game has been completed, the browser would ping the website with a verification code or scheme to say "hey, I'm done, and the javascript mini-game is complete".

There are two ways that I can think of to make the verification work.

1. One is a "replay" scheme, e.g. each
   of the moves that the user does
   would be concatenated and sent to
   the server, which would have a
   system for verifying that the end
   result was indeed a valid solved
   state.
2. The other is a "summary"
   verification code, for example if
   each of the numbers is assigned a
   random letter client-side, the final sliding puzzle state
   would result in a word-code like
   asdfaseasewadsfwef when read from left to right, top to bottom, which can be
   sent to the server upon completion
   to receive a pass/fail grade of
   success.  Obviously that isn't
   checking the intermediary steps,
   just the final result, but it'd
   probably be a lot faster and less
   resource-intensive, and would probably prevent a bit more abuse than just a GET request with a "go" parameter.

I don't have a huge, high bar for 100% secure communication in this case because I just want to add fun, and give some minor/non-overwhelming benefits from the mini-games, not build a fort-knox system.  And if someone is smart enough to hack up a solution to the mini-games to automate them, I won't be excessively broken up about it.

### Techniques?

So with that in mind, are these two approaches valid?  Are there other approaches to try with this?  Any examples in the wild that I could learn from?

Comment: I'd say if you're doing anything client-side, do what's easiest for you. A client will always exploit the game if he wants to, it's not worth the bother if the code is client-side. I agree with jhocking in going for the second solution, and agree that the majority of people will be deterred.

Comment: A couple of completely unrelated things, don't make a 5x5 version of this game, it doesn't really grow harder or more fun, it just takes more pushing around, and red numbers on a red background is never going to be a hit.

Comment: Yes indeed, the image is just one that I pulled from the web at random.  Even the sliding puzzle type is just an example, I'd like to come up with something more original, just need to get the groundwork of how to make it feasible down.

Answer (score 3):

**new answer**

(I thought of a better approach than what I wrote in the first place, but I'm leaving the original answer for reference)

Instead of having the client tell the server when the puzzle is completed, do it the other way around (ie. the server tells the client when the puzzle is completed). That way the client simply tells the server what move was made every time the player makes a move, and then the server can tell the client when the puzzle is complete in the response to the request from the client.

This way you get the security of option 1 without the bother of writing code to playback a series of moves.

---

**old answer**

Personally I would go with option 2 because you don't need this to be 100% secure. That is definitely a lot easier.

However, are you sure you don't care about cheating? Whether or not cheating on the mini-game matters depends on the reward for successfully completing the mini-game. If successfully completing the mini-game has any affect at all on other players, then I would consider cheating pretty important and go with option 1.

And note that "any affect" can be very subtle. Let's say that completing the mini-game just earns access to a new level for that one player. In that case, I wouldn't really care if they passed the mini-game by cheating. If however the mini-game earned them some visible trophy (eg. a badge on their profile) that other players can see then I would want to protect against cheating. And if the mini-game earned them a special weapon then I would *definitely* want to protect against cheating.

Comment: I guessed that as the game is in Javascript, @Tchalvak isn't all that bothered about cheating. You could verify everything server-side, but in the end the player could still too easily create a solver for the mini games. The verification would be huge work also compared with just simply deciding to use a different language.

Comment: Y'know what, I'm gonna change my answer because I thought of something better.

Comment: @jhoking ;) I hope i'm not annoying you? :P

Comment: no no, I was thinking about this anyway because I'm starting a job where I'm developing a Flash front-end to a multiplayer web-game. ActionScript is just as visible as JavaScript so it has the exact same security concerns.

Comment: Yes that's the way I made a checkers game a while back with AJAX :P. The user tells the server what he is moving, and the server tells him if he can, and what the consequences are. It's a lot of requests though (because the server can't __tell__ the client, he has to ask). Though it is probably the best solution for security & rapidity.

Answer (score 2):

Recording all the player moves and sending them to the server, is a good choice.

If you wanted more cheat protection, you could even have a key that is generated each move, using a seeded random number generator, using the the time in milliseconds for each key. Verify the moves and verify that the moves were created validly.

This will prevent people from packet sniffing and trying to spoof the moves with a solver program.

Comment: I agree that all moves should be sent to the server for validation. I don't understand how some random numbers would add to the protection? You can easily see in the JS code what's going on and spoof the same behavior (eg. adding some random numbers or spaced timestamps)

Comment: Its not just a random number, its a number and a timestamp that are verifiable on the server. You could make the method of creating the key extremely confusing to decipher and have small parts of it all over the entire codebase that seem unrelated but will cause the key to not be correct. It will not protect entirely from hackers, but it will make it require a lot of work to figure out how to send fake scores.

Comment: Making it extremely confusing and spreading the code/logic over the entire codebase will also make it very confusing and hard to maintain for yourself though :)

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't bother with a key generated on the client-side. You could have a key generated on the server that gets sent to the client when the mini-game starts, but even that seems pointless to me. The primary and only real security here would be replaying the game on the server, where you know it's legit.

Comment: I don't see why anyone would resort to packet sniffing on a Javascript game...

Comment: Well in my answer I mentioned the possibility of a mini-game that rewards the player with a special weapon. If the rewards are good enough, people will do anything.

Comment: @bummzack you could easily name the variables in the code something like "secretkeyPart1", and add comments so its easy to understand and fix. When publishing to the web, remove all the comments and minify or otherwise obfuscate all the variable names.